# Calender view Contain Month, Week, Day view in android 2.3+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I started the calendar APP containing Monthview, WeekView and DayView functionality..please give me some start ups...i have searched lot of sample projects but none of them are not useful to me.. please provide me any sample project.
But our team decided **not use google calender** instead of google calender there is any other support to make calender view for day and week view.

I tried to make month view using grid view it got worked me for android 2.3+

But how to make it for **Week view and Day view** any idea. This is new topic and great topic to research it.

Thank u in advance for your great idea.

my required screens are :
[image: DayView]

[image: WeekView]

Comment: You need to paste your code here. What have you tried?

Comment: pleas refer this link https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar